# Maven: Error resolving artifact - nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I have an OSGi (apache-karaf-4.0.1 with Java 7 and Apache Maven 3.3.9) project, which has been working, but today when I maven build it, it builds fine, but when I start it, it gets the following error:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error resolving artifact
> com.xxxxx.integration.suppliers.firstcar:com.xxxxxx.integration.supplier.firstcar.adaptor:jar:1.1.0re:
> Could not transfer artifact
> com.xxxxxx.integration.suppliers.firstcar:com.xxxxxx.integration.supplier.firstcar.adaptor:jar:1.1.0re
> from/to gemini
> (https://zodiac.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/):
> zodiac.springsource.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Is the zodiac.springsource.com repo unavailable?

The application does not have any direct reference to the zodiac.springsource.com repo,  but one of its dependencies probably do.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: zodiac.springsource.com does not resolve to a IP-Address, so yes, it is unavailable. :D

Comment: @Grim, yes, I cannot ping zodiac.springsource.com. I need to try identify which maven dependencies reference zodiac.springsource.com (not sure how at this stage).

Answer (score 1):

This must be related to some network/internet connection issue. I switched my connection. to my phones 3G connection, and it resolved the issue.